# Maplotlib calendar subplot need to avoid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

[image]

I tried to plot a calendar graphic with this code, I plot a graphic, but I do nοt know how to avoid the subplot, I adapted from other code.

Can you help to solve this error, please?

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

total_test = pd.read_csv('datos_pos_neg_peru.csv', sep=";")
df = total_test
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df[['Year', 'Month','Day']])
df = df.drop(['Year', 'Month','Day'], axis = 1)
df.rename(columns = {'Recuperdos_dia' : 'Temp'}, inplace = True)
df = df.groupby([df['Time'].dt.date]).mean()
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
cal = {'2020': df[df.index.year == 2020]}
DAYS = ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mier', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab','Dom']
MONTHS = ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize = (20,15))
for i, val in enumerate(['2020']):
    start = cal.get(val).index.min()
    end = cal.get(val).index.max()
    start_sun = start - np.timedelta64((start.dayofweek + 1) % 7, 'D')
    end_sun =  end + np.timedelta64(7 - end.dayofweek -1, 'D')
    num_weeks = (end_sun - start_sun).days // 7
    heatmap = np.full([7, num_weeks], np.nan)    
    ticks = {}
    y = np.arange(8) - 0.5
    x = np.arange(num_weeks + 1) - 0.5
    for week in range(num_weeks):
        for day in range(7):
            date = start_sun + np.timedelta64(7 * week + day, 'D')
            if date.day == 1:
                ticks[week] = MONTHS[date.month - 1]
            if date.dayofyear == 1:
                ticks[week] += f'\n{date.year}'
            if start <= date < end:
                heatmap[day, week] = cal.get(val).loc[date, 'Temp']
    mesh = ax[i].pcolormesh(x, y, heatmap, cmap = 'Reds', edgecolors = 'grey')
    ax[i].invert_yaxis()
    ax[i].set_xticks(list(ticks.keys()))
    ax[i].set_xticklabels(list(ticks.values()))
    ax[i].set_yticks(np.arange(7))
    ax[i].set_yticklabels(DAYS)
    ax[i].set_ylim(6.5,-0.5)
    ax[i].set_aspect('equal')
    ax[i].set_title(val, fontsize = 20)
    # Hatch for out of bound values in a year
    ax[i].patch.set(hatch='xx', edgecolor='grey'
cbar_ax = fig.add_axes([0.15, -0.10, 0.3, 0.05])
fig.colorbar(mesh, orientation="horizontal", pad=0.1, cax = cbar_ax)
r = colorbar.vmax - colorbar.vmin
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve). In particular we need the data or a sample of it.

Comment: I don't know how upload the data, I am really new in StackOverflow,

Comment: you could take a sample of your data and edit your post. Just add the output of  `df.head().to_dict()` or `df.head(n).to_dict()` where n is the number of row you want to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 1, ....)`. This means 2 rows, 1 column. If you only want one subplot, use `fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, ...)`. Thereafter, you should directly use `ax` instead of `ax[i]`.